# Programming set /p input

Tags: batch-file

I have two scripts. First script is asking user for some input and calling another script giving it the input as a parameter. Second script is again asking user for the same input.

*first.bat*

```
set /p input=Insert your input:
call second.bat %input%
```

*second.bat*

```
if %1 == "Y" input=%1 & goto skipInput
set /p input=Insert the same input:

:skipInput
echo Skipped user input
```

Is it possible to set second user input with first input value without user pressing the same input value? Problem is that `set /p` in *second.bat* cannot be skipped like in upper example.

**Updated solution:**

*first.bat*

```
set /p input=Insert your input:
echo %input% | (cd path/to/file & second.bat)
echo %input% | (cd path/to/file & second.bat)
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, but maybe this

*First.bat*

```
set /p input=Insert your input:
call second.bat %input%
```

*Second.bat*

```
if %1=="Y" set input=%1
```

Which will set the variable `input` in the second script to the value of `input` in the first script.

***Update***

If you only have access to the initial batch that calls the others then try this

```
@echo off
set /p input=Insert your input:
echo %input%| second.bat
pause >nul
```

After running that I managed to get the prompt in the second batch which just has the `set /p` line to be filled in using the pipe redirection.

Comment: The problem is that `set /p` in *second.bat* is asking user for input. In my case the *first.bat* is calling many .bat files which are asking user for the same user. So the user has to insert many times the same input. `set /p` must stay in the *second.bat* but I want to disable it so it will not wait for user input but will automatically insert value from the *first.bat*.

Comment: `set /p must stay in the second.bat but I want to disable it so it will not wait for user input but will automatically insert value from the first.bat` If you want to disable the prompt then why must you still have `set /p`? It sounds very contradictive.

Comment: I agree. If it could be done my way I would not use `set /p` in *second.bat* but that is not the case.

Comment: Sorry if I am being naive here, but why do you have to have `set /p` in the second? I just can't work out what you want to achieve.

Comment: I got this task and this scripts to use, but the scripts that are being called cannot be changed. That means that `set /p` must stay. Is it even possible to manipulate this without user interference?

Comment: Ok, see my update, I have managed to do this in a sample batch file. It doesn't use `call` and doesn't pass any parameters, but I haven't picked it apart enough to know if any tweaks will still work. Have a play around with it and see if it works for what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
:first.bat
cls
set /p input=Enter input.
if "%input%" equ "" goto first.bat
call seccond.bat %input%
```

What happens here is if the user's input is equal to "NUL" go back to the beginning.

```
:seccond.bat
cls
set input=%*
if /i "%input%" equ "Y" do command
```

Put your code below for SECCOND.bat